# A java exception has occuerred while running java code with selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run some simple Java code in Selenium. I am using JDK 1.7 and configured Selenium 3.0.0 with Eclipse. However all the Java code is executing properly.

Below is the code that I am trying to run and getting an error from Java Virtual Machine Launcher saying:

> "A java error has occurred"`.

```
package mypackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");}
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Add the stacktrace. Also do you have firefox installed on your computer?

Comment: yep, e.printStackTrace() instead of System.err.print(e.getMessage()); would be much more useful