# Selenium Web driver 3.3.1

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, firefox

I am using `Eclipse IDE` for `selenium 3.3.1`. I have added `selenium 3.3.1` jar files which were in and out of the lib folder.

```
Eclipse version is Helios Service Release 1. 
firefox version is 52.0.1(32 Bit). 
JDK version is 1.8.0_05.
```

But still i got the error

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox cannot be resolved.
```

I have also tried below code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\selenium-java-3.3.1\\geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
```

But, It didn't get work for me.

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377564/a-java-exception-has-occuerred-while-running-java-code-with-selenium

Comment: @alexandrum if it's a dup of that, it doesn't look like an obvious one to me

Comment: Maybe you copied the wrong JARs or did not add them to the build path.

Comment: @MarioTrucco It is not directly meant for import issue but more for property setting. The answer from the indicated question has a link with an example.

Comment: It's not applicable in version 3.3.1.   Below is the update from version 3.3.0                                                                             * Support for geckodriver v0.15.0.
* Deprecated seldom used FirefoxDriver constructors.
* Added javadocs to show best way to create a new FirefoxDriver:
  ```
  DesiredCapabilities caps = new FirefoxOptions()
       // For example purposes only
      .setProfile(new FirefoxProfile())
      .addTo(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(caps);

Answer (score 0):

Change "webdriver.firefox.marionette" to "webdriver.gecko.driver"

Comment: This is not going to do anything for the import not found error, which is a compile-time error.

Comment: Need to import following: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

Comment: @Kushal. I have tried that too. But the error is on the import .

Comment: Below were the import package suggested. But FirefoxDriver package is not listed. (1) Gecko Driver Service (2) Firefox Profile (3) Extension Connection (4) NotConnected Exception (5) UnableToCreateProfileException (6) firefoxamd64 (7) firefox.internal (8) firefoxx86

Comment: are you positive you have added following command: import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

Comment: @Kushal. I have added that too. Then i have installed selenium version 3.0.1. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

1) Update **firefox browser** version 52 or above 
2) Update the selenium java jar files, you can download updated jar files from this [site](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/).
3) Update the **gecko driver** as well, you can download updated gecko driver from this [site](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

For more details on how to update above settings in eclipse, refer this [site](http://www.guru99.com/installing-selenium-webdriver.html).

Now restart your eclipse once and try to run your automation script.

Comment: Have you try this solution?